# To print the number of steps this RandomQuickSort Takes. Java code

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, printing

I have this Java algorithm and I am having trouble printing the number of steps it takes to solve the sorting. Here is the code

```
    /* The main function that implements QuickSort()
    arr[] --> Array to be sorted,
    low --> Starting index,
    high --> Ending index */
    static void sort(int arr[], int low, int high)
    {
        if (low < high)
        {
            /* partIndex is partitioning index, arr[partIndex] is
            now at right place */
            int partIndex = partition(arr, low, high);
 
            // Recursively sort elements before
            // partition and after partition
            sort(arr, low, partIndex-1);
            sort(arr, partIndex+1, high);
        }
    }
 
    /*  print array of size n */
    static void printArray(int arr[])
    {
        int n = arr.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
        System.out.println();
    }
 
    // Driver Code
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int[] data = {12,9,4,99,120,1,3,10,23,45,75,69,31,88,101,14,29,91,2,0,77};
               
        System.out.println("Unsorted Array \n" + " "); 
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(data)+ "\n");
        
        int n = data.length;
        RandomQuicSort.sort(data, 0, n - 1);
 
        //sort(data, 0, n-1);
 
        System.out.println("Sorted array in ascending order");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data)+"\n"); 
        System.out.println("Sorting was completed in: " ); 
        
        printArray(data);
    }
}
```

This is the output.

```
Unsorted Array 
 
[12, 9, 4, 99, 120, 1, 3, 10, 23, 45, 75, 69, 31, 88, 101, 14, 29, 91, 2, 0, 77]
9   Was swapped with    120
1   Was swapped with    9
0   Was swapped with    1
3   Was swapped with    10
9   Was swapped with    10
23  Was swapped with    101
23  Was swapped with    75
14  Was swapped with    23
69  Was swapped with    77
31  Was swapped with    75
31  Was swapped with    45
91  Was swapped with    120
101 Was swapped with    120
Sorted array in ascending order
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 12, 14, 23, 29, 31, 45, 69, 75, 77, 88, 91, 99, 101, 120]

Sorting was completed in: 
0 1 2 3 4 9 10 12 14 23 29 31 45 69 75 77 88 91 99 101 120
```

I would like to change the last line `Sorting was completed in:`to display the number of steps the algorithm took to put the array in ascending order. Not the sorted array like it is now. For example, if the algorithm took 30 steps, I need to display `Sorting was completed in: 30 Steps!`. I have tried printing `class.display();` but it gives me an error message.

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: How is this related to Python?

Comment: Usually, people who know java also know python. Maybe my assumption is wrong and I apologize for wrong tag

Comment: Fairly obvious the python tag was a mistake. OP if I'm understanding you you want to count each invocation of the sort method. If so would a simple static int help? And you increment it by one each time the sort method is invoked?

Comment: @ConorTimlin What would the solution that you recommend look like? I think I understand what you are saying but can't visualize it. 

I am new to programming and a lot of things still don't come easy to me.

Comment: I'd need to whack it out in an IDE to be sure (look into what the static modifier means in java) basically you'd define a class level variable called stepsToSort or whatever. Initialize it to 0. Then at the very end of your sort methods just before they make the recursive call to the sort method, they should increment the stepsToSort variable by 1.

Comment: @ConorTimlin. I use this online compiler. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php

For some reason, my IntelliJ breaks down every two days and stops working. So I found this to be easier.

Comment: I'd recommend eclipse for beginner java programming. Not familiar with online IDEs but I'd imagine downloaded one is better

Comment: I actually set up eclipse today. Looks very user-friendly. I will try to find help elsewhere as well. Thanks for the recommendations.

Comment: @ConorTimlin I was able to make it work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Excellent. Glad it was of use to you. I might post the solution as an Answer so you can mark the post solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of the invokations of the sort method with a static member and increment it by one each time the sort function is run like so

```
    class RandomQuicSort
{    
    // This Function helps in calculating
    // the inclusive high and low
    public static int stepsToSort = 0;

    static void random(int arr[],int low,int high)
```

Then at the end of your sort method just increment it like this

```
static void sort(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        /* partIndex is partitioning index, arr[partIndex] is
        now at right place */
        int partIndex = partition(arr, low, high);

        // Recursively sort elements before
        // partition and after partition
        stepsToSort++;
        sort(arr, low, partIndex-1);
        sort(arr, partIndex+1, high);

     
    }
}
```

Comment: This only counts. I was having issues with the printing. The problem was I wasn’t calling the method in order to use the “class.display()”. Thank you for helping me. :)